# Select the newest record

Tags: sql, hiveql

[image: Here is my dataset.]

I would like to run a select statement that runs and select only the newest record by Recored_timestampe field for the keys teacher_id and student_id. So any time, it runs it needs to provide only one record. how could I do it, please? The output could be without the field Recored_timestampe. Thanks

Comment: Only one record?  Or one record per pair?  What if there are multiple students and teachers in the table?

Comment: I have changed that a bit - but in any way, it needs to be only one record from even if there are many with the same keys.  The student_id might be found as a null value sometimes, but the record needs still to be valid for selection.  I would like to select first the newest record that has sutdnet_id and if all the student_id is null for the same teacher_id, the newest record will be selected.  Could you help me with that, please?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVFql.png Here are some examples

Answer (score 1):

First, arrange the record by datetime

```
     SELECT *,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY Recored_timestamp desc) as ranking
     FROM #temp
```

Then, if you want to know the newest record with student_id which is not null, then you can use `OUTER APPLY` to add a column which is non-NULL student_id.

```
OUTER APPLY (SELECT student_id 
             FROM #temp 
             WHERE #temp.teacher_id = ranktable.teacher_id 
               AND student_id IS NOT NULL
            ) AS jointable
```

Here is an example:

```
Create Table #temp
(
     teacher_id int
    ,student_id int
    ,teacher_name varchar(40)
    ,comment varchar(100)
    ,Recored_timestamp datetime
)

INSERT INTO #temp 
VALUES
 (449,111,'lucy','Could be better','2021-05-04 07:00:00.000')
,(449,null,'lucy','smily','2021-05-11 07:00:00.000')
,(449,111,'lucy','not listening','2021-05-08 07:00:00.000')
,(448,null,'Toni','Good','2021-06-04 09:00:00.000')
,(448,222,'Toni','not doing as expected','2021-06-04 08:00:00.000')

SELECT DISTINCT teacher_id,
                jointable.student_id,
                teacher_name,
                comment,
                Recored_timestamp,
                ranking
FROM
(
     SELECT *,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY teacher_id ORDER BY Recored_timestamp DESC) AS ranking
     FROM #temp
) AS ranktable
OUTER APPLY (SELECT student_id 
             FROM #temp 
             WHERE #temp.teacher_id = ranktable.teacher_id 
               AND student_id IS NOT NULL
            ) AS jointable   
WHERE ranking = 1 --only newest record will be extracted

Drop table #temp
```

Comment: Thanks! I have found some cases today that slightly change the target of it. The student_id might be found as a null value sometimes, but the record needs still to be valid for selection.  I want first to select the newest record that has sutdnet_id and if all the student_id is null for the same teacher_id, the newest record will be selected.  Could you help me with that please?

Comment: @Matias021 I have edited my answer. You can try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Using the window function,partitioned by teacher_id and student_id and sorting it by recorded_timestamp will give you the desired result.

`select * from(select teacher_id,student_id,teacher_name,comment ,recorded_timestamp, row_number() over(partition by teacher_id,student_id order by recorded_timestamp desc)as rownum from temp0607)out1 where rownum=1`

Also you may have to look at the way recorded_timestamp is stored. If it is stored as string, you can convert it into timestamp using `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(recorded_timestamp,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'),'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')`

Comment: Thanks! I have found some cases today that slightly change the target of it. The student_id might be found as a null value sometimes, but the record needs still to be valid for selection.  I want first to select the newest record that has sutdnet_id and if all the student_id is null for the same teacher_id, the newest record will be selected.  Could you help me with that please?

Comment: @Matias021 can you add some sample records and the output you are expecting for the scenarios you mentioned. This would help in coming up with the solution.Also I assume that for every teacher, student combination you are expecting a single row as output right?

Comment: Here it is for you https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVFql.png

Answer (score 0):

You can base from this query to get the newest data.

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM *tablename* *T1*
INNER JOIN(SELECT *teacher_id*, Max(*Recored_timestamp*) as MaxDate from *tablename* GROUP BY *teacher_id*) T2 ON T2.*teacher_id* = T1.*teacher_id* AND T1.*Recored_timestamp* = T2.MaxDate